# Get the source repository of a pull request

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pull-request

I am using multibranch pipeline jobs & have a usecase of doing a PR build. On a PR, I want to checkout the source repository of that PR. Is there any way I can get that in jenkins pipeline?

PS: I know "checkout scm" does this automatically. But I want to do this checkout over ssh & I could not find any way to overwride the https url used by checkout scm module

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to do this checkout over ssh & I could not find any way to overwride the https url used by checkout scm module

If that module ([Git Jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git)) is doing regular `git` commands, then it should respect global git configuration like [`url.<base>.InsteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-urlltbasegtinsteadOf).

If you know with which account Jenkins is running, you could, on that Jenkins server, type:

```
git config --global url.git@server.com.InsteadOf https://server.com
```

That would force Git to use an SSH URL, even though the checkout used initially an HTTPS one.